# how to show default placeholder in angular ng-select model?

Tags: angular8, dropdown, angular-ngselect

so when my form group get loaded my drop down looks like this

[image]

my ng select code is

```
 <ng-select 
     placeholder="select By Device"
     appendTo="ng-select"
     [clearable]="true"
     [searchable]="true"  
     formControlName="byDevice">
            <ng-option [value]="1">Desktop</ng-option>
            <ng-option [value]="2">Laptop</ng-option>
            <ng-option [value]="3">Tablet</ng-option>
            <ng-option [value]="4">Mobile</ng-option>  
     </ng-select>
```

I want clearable option true because its filter

and when i click on close icon (clearable icon) i see placeholder like this

[image]

basically it should look like this when it gets loaded instead of empty option

so how do i do this

please help !!

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I resolved issue you just have to assign null value to form control name

```
  this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    'byDevice':new FormControl(null)
  });
```

like this

Thanks !!